# Worksheet_Change Not Being Triggered

Tags: excel, vba

I am not sure why worksheet_change is not firing. Although the code gives no bugs, the excel sheet doesn't change. It seems like the code is not running.

I have a series of functions which rely on each other and they are all called by the worksheet_change sub. I have made sure to disable and enable events when making changes to prevent the "out of stack space" error.

```
Function get_used()

Dim Header As Range
Dim Cell As Range
Dim Used As Double
Dim EndCol As Integer

EndCol = Sheets("Monthly Cash Balances").Range("L2").End(xlToRight).Column
Set Header = Range(Cells(2, 12), Cells(2, EndCol))

For Each Cell In Header
    If Cell.Value = "Actual" Then
    Used = Used + Cell.Offset(14, 0)
    End If
Next Cell

get_used = Used

End Function


Function get_rmonths(ByVal start_date As Date, ByVal end_date As Date)

Dim Header As Range
Dim Cell As Range
Dim RMonths As Integer
Dim StartCol As Integer
Dim EndCol As Integer

EndCol = Sheets("Monthly Cash Balances").Range("L3").End(xlToRight).Column
Set Header = Range(Cells(2, 12), Cells(2, EndCol))

For Each Cell In Header
    If Cell.Value <> "Actual" And Cell.Offset(1, 0).Value >= start_date And Cell.Offset(1, 0).Value <= end_date Then
        RMonths = RMonths + 1
    End If
Next Cell

get_rmonths = RMonths

End Function


Function SLdist(Amount As Double)

Dim Used As Double
Dim RAmount As Double
Dim DAmount As Double
Dim RMonths As Integer
Dim EndCol As Integer
Dim Header As Range
Dim Cell As Range

EndCol = Sheets("Monthly Cash Balances").Range("L3").End(xlToRight).Column
Set Header = Range(Cells(2, 12), Cells(, EndCol))

Used = get_used()
RAmount = Amount - Used
RMonths = get_rmonths(Sheets("Monthly Cash Balances").Range("F16").Value, Sheets("Monthly Cash Balances").Range("G16").Value)
DAmount = RAmount / RMonths

For Each Cell In Header
    If Cell.Value <> "Actual" And Cell.Offset(1, 0).Value >= start_date And Cell.Offset(1, 0).Value <= end_date Then
        Cell.Offset(14, 0).Value = RAmount
    End If
Next Cell

End Function


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Amount As Double

Amount = Sheets("Monthly Cash Balances").Range("D16").Value

Application.EnableEvents = False

SLdist Amount

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your code or put a *breakpoint* in the `Worksheet_Change` event to test the code is/is not being entered? What are you doing to trigger the event?

Comment: I was not sure how to do troubleshoot it since the code gave no errors. I think the problem is that the I have put the enable/disable around the change event and so the work_sheet change cant detect the change made. Is there a better solution than the enable/disable method?

Comment: Using the `Application.EnableEvents` simply stops the code from entering any events, such as the `Worksheet_Change` event, it won't stop changes being made on your worksheet by either manual input or changes by your code. Try testing per my first comment and step through the code, that way you can see what the code is (or isn't) doing.

Comment: Enter `? Application.EnableEvents` in the Immediate pane and press enter.  If it gives you `False` then your event handler may have exited (maybe due to an error) while events were turned off.  `Application.EnableEvents = True` in the Immediate pane will re-enable events.  Is your `Worksheet_Change` in the sheet code module?

Comment: I used breakpoints and as the immediate pane to narrow down the issue. Thanks for the help! The issue is that values at cell.offset(1,0) (which is a range of dates) are not recognized. If I print their value to a cell, they simply print to nothing (blank). Cell.offset(10,0) (which are numbers) prints the actual numbers. Not sure why

Comment: You have Range/Cells calls with no qualifying worksheet object, so by default they will reference the ActiveSheet: that may not be what you expect/want.